# Element type "rotate" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Tags: android, animation, view

I am trying to use view animation on an Imageview object.I have defined a rotate.xml file for the same.But I am getting   couple of errors in the file:-

1)Element type "rotate" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
2)error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Here is my rotate.xml file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="180"
    android:pivotX="50"
    android:pivotY="50"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:duration="3000">

</rotate>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `</rotate>` and replace `>` with `/>` it could be trying to interpret the space between <rotate> and </rotate> ?

Comment: Try Project->Clean. In my project doesn't show any errors.

Comment: @Justin, Your suggestion worked.The problem was the space interpretation.
I solved this issue by using Android file creator to create explicitly the animation xml file named rotate.xml  and then putting each property one by one.

Comment: @Justin this is fine with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you remove `</rotate>` and replace `>` with `/>` it could be trying to interpret the space between `<rotate>` and `</rotate>`

Comment: @ruchira - Please accept this answer, so people know that this fixed your problem.